# Getting Interface 'Response<ResBody>' incorrectly extends interface 'Response'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Im using typescript and express in node.js and when I compile it I get
When I compile from typescript I get this bug

```
node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts:505:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'Response<ResBody>' incorrectly extends interface 'Response'.
  Types of property 'locals' are incompatible.
    Type 'Record<string, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'i18nAPI': locale, __, __n, __mf, and 5 more.

505 export interface Response<ResBody = any> extends http.ServerResponse, Express.Response {
                     ~~~~~~~~
```

from my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/i18n": "^0.8.6",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.7",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.26",
    "@types/node-schedule": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/ws": "^7.2.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.7.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.7",
    "chokidar": "^3.4.1",
    "dblapi.js": "^2.4.0",
    "discord.js": "^12.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^23.18.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "findit2": "^2.2.3",
    "i18n": "^0.10.0",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.2",
    "npm-check-updates": "^7.0.3",
    "tree-kill": "^1.2.2",
    "ts-jest": "^26.1.4",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
}
```

Anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this error. I first tried to re-create this as a minimal code needed to re-produce (in a sub folder in my main project) and everything worked fine, and then I started copying all my main files into that minimal example and it still worked. Pretty soon I had my whole project in that sub folder and it worked there. So then I just deleted my main code and moved the sub folder contents up a level and it still worked there...... Not sure what is the difference. I have a hunch it may be the ordering of dependencies listed in the package.json might of changed which made it work...

Ref: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/46639

Answer (score 18):

Try `npm i -D @types/express-serve-static-core`, enable `skipLibCheck` is not a good idea.

Answer (score 10):

Add `"skipLibCheck": true` in **tsconfig.json**. It worked for me.

Comment: If you're going to do this you should [understand the consequences of doing so](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck). 9 times out of 10, this is not the right thing to do

Answer (score 2):

`skipLibCheck` is rather a workaround and you should not include it without knowing what you are doing.

The issue is fixed in the latest versions so if you have `@types/express` install update it to latest `npm i -D @types/express@latest` or install `@types/express-serve-static-core` explicitly with `npm i -D @types/express-serve-static-core`

You can check which version the `@types/express-serve-static-core` has with:

```
$ npm ls @types/express-serve-static-core

redacted@2.1.4 /path/redacted
└─┬ @types/express@4.17.13
  └── @types/express-serve-static-core@4.17.28
```

From: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/46639

Answer (score -1):

I'm getting exactly the same thing. I downgraded to the previous version (4.0.53) from the current version (4.17.9). Seems to be an issue in the latest release.

Comment: Could be. Also I was able to fix it, see here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/46639